# MongoDB: How to find the relationships between collections in database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a collection of `user` which has `id, firstName, lastName`. `id` field of `user` collection has been used in another collection.

Is there any way to find all collection which used **user id**?

user schema:

```
let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  }
},
{
  timestamps: true,
  usePushEach: true
});
```

training schema:

```
var trainingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  institution: {
    instituteName: {type: String, required: true},
    type: {type: String, required: true},
    address: {
      country: String,
      state: String,
      city: String
    }
  },
  startDate: Date,
  endDate: Date,
  achievements: String,
  createdAt: Date,
  updatedAt: Date,
  endorsers: [{
    userId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    },
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    profilePic: {
      container: {type: String,default: null},
      name: { type: String, default: null }
    },
    currentPosition: {type: String,default: ""},
    currentWorkingCompany: {type: String,default: ""}
  }],
});
```

In above schema **userId** come from **user** collection

Note: similar to this  which is available in MYSQL:

```
SELECT 
    ke.referenced_table_name 'parent table',
    ke.referenced_column_name 'parent column',
    ke.table_name 'child table',
    ke.column_name 'child column',
    ke.constraint_name
FROM
    information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ke
WHERE
    ke.referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL
        AND table_schema = 'your_db_name'
ORDER BY ke.referenced_table_name;
```

Source: [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60736/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-cardinality-between-tables-from-a-mysql-database)

Comment: Why down vote. the similar thing we have in MYSQL

Comment: You can use `$lookup` here... But don't know what do you mean by *Is there any way to find all collection which used user id?*

Comment: `$lookup` is used when I want to get one by one. assume that I don't know which collection has used the `user`.

Comment: I haven't seen this type of thing  or aggregation in mongodb yet... What you are seeking for is not possible as much as I know about mongodb

Comment: At least there has to be some way.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need MySQL function named join. In MongoDB it is named [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and it is part of [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) function.

Comment: please check the question, I have edited my question.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you posted part with actual mongodb and javascript

Comment: I added sample schema

Comment: I am not quite sure what is task here. If it is what I think it is, using lookup to "connect" collections is solution.

Comment: `$lookup` is used when I know all the collection relation. assume that I don't know which collection has used the `user` collection, and I have more than 100 collections.

Comment: I never used and never seen such function in mongodb. I may be wrong and there may be  solution but not that I know of